# Repetitive tasks?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I am currently working on a puzzle, that will inevitably have some manual repetitive tasks in parts. To eliminate this, I am considering doing the tasks myself and putting it in a pastebin. When the puzzle has been solved up to the correct point, I will release the pastebin link so solvers won't have to do it themselves. Should I do this though? Would it be better if solvers completed the whole puzzle by themselves?

Comment: IMO, if your puzzle has repetitive tasks, then it's probably a badly designed puzzle. (I could be wrong though.)

Comment: @Deusovi I hope you're wrong :) The repetitive task is a sort of cipher (like Braille or Morse to decode) except it has to be deciphered by hand and there are lots of letters.

Comment: Deciphering a long cipher *by hand*? That's exactly what I was worried about.

Comment: @Deusovi I know it sounds bad but it's just a small part of the wider puzzle. Would it be better if I did the repetitive bit myself then (as I asked in the question)?

Comment: I am trying not to spoil to much, but the enciphered form would be more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Why not have your solved version be revealed from some other small hidden puzzle, like an imagur link encoded by the first few characters being decoded?

Comment: [Is there something bad about this puzzle?](//meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/3205/19765) mentions the concept of "hard/fun balance", which seems to be relevant here.

Answer (score 6):

An enthusiastic **yes**
to a thoughtfully considerate, generous and liberating
idea with value well beyond repetitive tasks!
 
This question could more broadly be redubbed:

## Laborious tasks?

Here are some benefits of the suggestion in
question — that
a puzzle’s poser provide results of
laborious portions of the solution,
at pose time or later.

- It is **considerate**
  to reduce the *un* creative effort required
  to fill out mechanically-derived details.
- It is **generous**
  to share results of mechanical labor that already
  went into creating and test-solving the puzzle.
  Usually the poser has generated such results
  much more efficiently than solvers would think of
  *or even have good tools for*.
- It is **liberating**
  to be able, with a clear conscience,
  to create puzzles with many details
  when onerous ramifications of those details
  are not burdened upon solvers.

Such results can readily be supplied in the form of
an auxiliary answer to the puzzle — such as
a “wikified worksheet”— *here*
rather than off site when possible.
To answer as a community wiki
not only averts a taint of vote begging
but also encourages solvers to share results of further efforts.
 
Such an answer can exploit other benefits as well.

- Help clarify the puzzle
  while allowing the original statement to remain relatively concise.
- Exemplify a format for solutions.
- Highlight clues and provide hints, both overtly and subtly.
- Help divert solvers from extensive efforts along false leads.

### Related examples

Please add to this list, as existing examples or,
even better of course, as newly created examples.

- [***Welcome to Nᴏɴᴇderland***](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/39009/welcome-to-n%e1%b4%8f%c9%b4%e1%b4%87derland)
  –
  An [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) with data so overwhelming that
  to deny solvers a helping hand would simply be unfair.

  [Wikified worksheet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/39010/18129)
  –
  Not only laborious but drenched in clues and unstated hints.
- [***ABC - A Blokus Commitment***](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35195/abc-a-blokus-commitment)
  –
  An excellent example of broader uses for auxiliary answers,
  which further spurred additions from others than the poser.

  [Examples of perfect boards](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/36109/18129)
  –
  Invaluable clarification of the puzzle.

  [Examples of related solutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/36033/18129)
  –
  Both a clarification of the puzzle
  and a helpful guide to solution.
- [***Some string of letters***](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28097/some-string-of-letters)
  –
  The first puzzle where I experimented with this kind of approach.

   
  [Initial worksheet/hint](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/28435/1)
  –
  Provided after a week of no apparent solution activity,
  and after suspecting that the puzzle came off as a
  [vomit cipher](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do).
   
  Not the best example, being inadequately introduced,
  this worksheet was not readily recognizable as an attempt to be helpful.

   
  [Converted to a making-of wrap-up](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28435/18129)
  –
  Seemed like a good new purpose for the worksheet
  after the puzzle was solved with no discussion.
- [***Third timer’s a charm***](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33882/third-timers-a-charm)
  –
  An essentially simple puzzle
  whose unfamiliar nature required such an unwieldy setup
  that further explanation seemed susceptible
  to collapse under its own weight.

  [Sample solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/35181/18129)
  –
  Effectively just a continuation of the puzzle statement.

Answer (score 3):

*Some* manual repetition is likely okay, buuuut... **please be respectful of solvers' time.**

I won't elaborate a whole lot on that, because it's more true if it's left as an intuitive general principle. But if you think there's a part of your puzzle that's going to take a lot of time and work slogging through fairly unrewarding manual trials, consider that the puzzle might simply be better if it weren't there.